# OpenCV JS/WASM build fails attempting to add face module

Tags: javascript, opencv

I opened an issue for OpenCV.
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/17597

I build in Ubuntu 20 environment. OpenCV and OpenCV_contrib are the latest from master branch.

Desperately need to build OpenCV/WASM/ASMJS with face modules included:

```
face = {'': ['createFacemarkLBF', 'createFacemarkAAM',  'createFacemarkKazemi', 'drawFacemarks'],\
        'Facemark': ['fit', 'loadModel'], \
        'FacemarkLBF': [], \
        'FacemarkAAM': [], \
        'FacemarkKazemi': [], \
        }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Error log:

```
100%] Generating bindings.cpp
cd /home/svg/opencv/build_wasm/modules/js && /usr/bin/python2.7 /home/svg/opencv/modules/js/src/embindgen.py /home/svg/opencv/modules/js/../python/src2/hdr_parser.py /home/svg/opencv/build_wasm/modules/js/bindings.cpp /home/svg/opencv/build_wasm/modules/js/headers.txt /home/svg/opencv/modules/js/src/core_bindings.cpp
Generator error: unable to resolve base face::Facemark for face_FacemarkKazemi
make[3]: *** [modules/js/CMakeFiles/opencv_js.dir/build.make:143: modules/js/bindings.cpp] Error 255
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/svg/opencv/build_wasm'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3856: modules/js/CMakeFiles/opencv_js.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/svg/opencv/build_wasm'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3825: modules/js/CMakeFiles/opencv.js.dir/rule] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/svg/opencv/build_wasm'
make: *** [Makefile:691: opencv.js] Error 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./platforms/js/build_js.py", line 284, in <module>
    builder.build_opencvjs()
  File "./platforms/js/build_js.py", line 202, in build_opencvjs
    execute(["make", "-j", str(multiprocessing.cpu_count()), "opencv.js"])
  File "./platforms/js/build_js.py", line 23, in execute
    raise Fail("Child returned: %s" % retcode)
__main__.Fail: Child returned: 2
```